# Get a post from other loop each n-posts in the main loop

Tags: wp-query, loop

Here's the layout, I'd like to achieve.

- 1st row: three posts in three columns from category A
- 2nd row: one fullwidth post from category B
- 3rd row: the next three posts from category A
- 4th row: the next post from category B
- etc.

It looks like this:

```
-------------------------
| CAT A | CAT A | CAT A |
-------------------------
|         CAT B         |
-------------------------
| CAT A | CAT A | CAT A |
-------------------------
|         CAT B         |
-------------------------
| CAT A | CAT A | CAT A |
-------------------------
|         CAT B         |
```

Basically there are two loops, one inside each other, running in parallel and individually.

I can get the number of current post of the main loop by `$wp_query->current_post` and insert a new `WP_Query` after each third post with only one post (by `posts_per_page=>1`) and offset by the number of previous posts (by `offset=>$wp_query->current_post`).

I'm afraid this is a very memory intensive thing to call a new WP_query after each third post. Are there any better alternatives to display posts in the markup I specified above? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do. At the top of your page, run your first WP_Query. Calculate the number of posts you need for your secondary query by using the number of posts IN query `cat_a` divided by 3 and using [PHP floor()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) to drop any remainder. This will ensure that your second query only has the exact number of posts needed to get the pattern your desire.

When displaying we can use [PHP Modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to display our `cat_b` post before `cat_a` 4 ( increments ) ever displays. In this case I enter The Loop of `cat_b` but [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) out so WordPress keeps track of where we are in our loop and we don't need to.

Altogether, the idea looks something like this. I haven't tested any of it so if you run into issues [turn on debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and see if you can fix any PHP errors.

```
$cat_b = '';
$cat_a = new WP_Query( array(
    'category'          => 'a',
    'posts_per_page'    => 60,
) );

if( $cat_a->have_posts() ) {
    $num_posts = floor( $cat_a->post_count / 3 );

    if( $num_posts > 0 ) {
        $cat_b = new WP_Query( array(
            'category'      => 'b',
            'posts_per_page'=> $num_posts,
        ) );
    }
}


if( $cat_a->have_posts() ) : $index = 1; ?>

    <?php while( $cat_a->have_posts() ) : $cat_a->the_post(); ?>

        <?php if( ! empty( $cat_b ) && 0 == $index % 4 && $cat_b->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while( $cat_b->have_posts() ) : $cat_b->the_post();

                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

            <?php
                wp_reset_postdata();
                break;
                endwhile;
            ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php
        $index++;
        endwhile;
    ?>

<?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
?>
```